# How to use different theme for single block?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

At first material ui theme defined at the root of project and it spreads on all pages. But I need to customize one block on page. And that block has to have different theme.

Project structure looks like:

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="gallery" component={Gallery} />
      <Route path="editor" component={Editor} />
      <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Edotor page

```
 <Layout>
    <Header /> // uses main theme
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={editorTheme}>
        <Editor />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    <Footer /> // uses main theme
 </Layout>
```

Are there will be performance issues if editor page props often changes and it calls render method?

Comment: Yes, you can put the Contex (Provider at any level). Just keep in mind that the properties on the Context will be accessible just for its child components

Comment: There is a related issue:https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15914, you may need another approach rather than simply nesting the `ThemeProvider`